# Upload Go project to GitHub Repository

Tags: go, github

How can i successfully upload my Go project to existing github repository? Here is how my **$GOPATH** looks like: `/home/user/go`.

There I have created the following directories: **`src/github.com/StefanCepa/`** . And inside that directory I have 2x directories which represent two different projects. I would like each of those projects to be posted on seperate github repository.

Any ideas how can I do that? Commiting stuff written in Go on github is kinda confusing to me.

Comment: Create a repo on Github for each of the directories. Github shows instructions for the next steps after you create the repo.  The process for creating a repo containing Go code is the same as the process for a repo containing code written in any language.

Comment: "Commiting stuff written in Go on github is kinda confusing to me" - then forget it's written in Go, because it's irrelevant. It's just files. Create a repo and commit the files.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is done the same way that you would initialize and commit a new repository regardless of the language.

Go just makes it a little easier to find your other Go projects thanks to the $GOPATH and the standards of the language. Simple example below.

*Within project 1:*

```
$ cd ~/go/src/github.com/StefanCepa/projectOne/
$ git init
$ git add .
$ git commit -m 'init'
$ git remote add origin https://github.com/StefanCepa/projectOne.git
$ git push -u origin master
```

*Within project 2:*

*same process as above